# Replace whole given words with each other in awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed

Let's say I have a file with such content:

```
hello
bye
bye
asd
hello
```

I'd like to exchange *hello* with *bye* and vice versa (that's only example so please dont stick to those words).

I've tried with:

```
sed -e 's/hello/bye/I g;s/bye/hello/I g' input.txt > output.txt
```

but as you can imagine that changed only *bye* to *hello* and *hello* remained unchanged.

Comment: Can the two terms appear on the same line ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21061/cleanly-swap-all-occurences-of-two-strings-using-sed

Comment: If your real problem is essentially as simple as the example given, and the two terms can appear in the same line: Use three steps: hello->newbye, bye->hello, newbye->bye

Comment: I should add that, only one term per line. @TomRegner your idea may work. I have few words to exchanged. Maybe it will not looks elegant but may work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^hello$/{ s/.*/bye/;b }; /^bye$/{ s/.*/hello/ }' file
```

> `b label`: Branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.

Output:

```
bye
hello
hello
asd
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/\<hello\>/\x00/ig;s/\<bye\>/hello/ig;s/\x00/bye/g' file
```

Use the `-z` option to slurp the file into memory.

Replace each `hello` by a zero byte.

Replace each `bye` by `hello`.

Replace each zero byte by `bye`.

N.B. With the option `-z` the strings accepted into the pattern space are delimited by  zero bytes.